# Multithreading freezes UI

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have a mutlithreaded WPF app. But after some background threads are launched, the UI is freezing (the display and the UI inputs).
Here is a simplified (but complete) example :

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Multithreading.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Scores, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FrameRates, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1"
        Content="New Thread" Click="Button_NewThread_Click" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            Content="UI test" Click="Button_UItest_Click"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

code-behind :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace WPF_Multithreading
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private List<Thread> threads;

    ObservableCollection<int> _scores;
    public ObservableCollection<int> Scores
    {
        get { return _scores; }
        set { _scores = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Scores"); }
    }

    ObservableCollection<int> _framerates;
    public ObservableCollection<int> FrameRates
    {
        get { return _framerates; }
        set { _framerates = value; RaisePropertyChanged("FrameRates"); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Scores = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        FrameRates = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        threads = new List<Thread>();
    }

    ~MainWindow()
    {
        foreach (Thread t in threads) t.Abort();
    }

    private void Button_NewThread_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(backgroundRun);

        Scores.Add(0);
        FrameRates.Add(0);
        t.Start(this);
        threads.Add(t);

    }

    private void backgroundRun(object o)
    {
        MainWindow _this = (MainWindow)o;

        int index = _this.Scores.Count()-1;
        Random r = new Random();

        DateTime prevDT = DateTime.Now;

        int nbiterations = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            // simulate computation
            nbiterations = 0;
            while((DateTime.Now-prevDT).Milliseconds < 50)
            {
                nbiterations++;
            }

            // Update UI
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    _this.Scores[index] = nbiterations;// r.Next();
                    _this.FrameRates[index] = (DateTime.Now - prevDT).Milliseconds;
                });

            prevDT = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    private void Button_UItest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("UI input ok");
    }

}
}
```

In this example I have to launch a lot of threads to make UI freezing but in my more complex app (displaying 2D graphics), only 2 or 3 threads would make it happen (with freezing for more than 10 seconds sometimes).
My question is then : is there a way to ensure the Dispatcher to have enough resource to unfreeze UI (especially inputs) ?

Comment: Multithreading doesn't freeze the UI. Hitting it every 10 ms though will. What *do* you invoke every 10 ms on the UI thread? That's the culprit. Why don't you use a timer with a sensible interval instead? Or data binding, so that you *don't* have to hit the UI thread at all? Please post a minimal, complete example. This snippet simply shows that you hit the UI too often

Comment: Actually, the "background stuff" takes about 100ms. The `Sleep` function was here to try to give some space to the Dispatcher. I use data binding (Properties are updated inside the Invoke Action). I can complete my example soon, sorry for its poorness

Comment: For multiple quick clicks, you can consider using a queue to store your clicks to simulate some delay between your clicks.

Comment: @olivier if you use data binding, why do you need Invoke? Simply raising the `PropertyChanged` event at the end of a loop should be enough. If you change a lot of properties, delaying the PropertyChanged event until the end of the loop will reduce UI thrashing. Also, did you set the `Async` data binding attribute to true? Please post the binding expressions and at least some snippet of your MVVM.

Comment: Replaced my poor code with a complete example.  @Panagiotis I iniatially raised the propertyChanged without `Dispatcher.Invoke` but it freezed more.  btw, the effect seems similar with `BeginInvoke` than with nothing.

Comment: First, why are you trying to mimic Tasks? Second, you are still hitting the UI every 50 ms and forcing *full redraws* of the controls. If you wanted to create some sort of animation, why don't you use WPF animations? Your contrived example has absolutely nothing to do with the performance of WPF's hardware accelerated 2D animation classes